# pass variables from main gulpfile.js to tasks across multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

In [Gulp Recipes](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/) there's one about [splitting gulp tasks across multiple files](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md).

Example:

```
gulpfile.js
tasks/
├── dev.js
├── release.js
└── test.js
```

In `gulpfile.js` I've variable `config` containing configs or paths.

How can I pass `config` variable from `gulpfile.js` to other tasks across multiple files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put that config variable in it's own file and then require it in the other files needing it

Answer (score 3):

You can define a global variable that will be available in all required modules. However, make sure to define this variable in your Gulpfile and never change it's value anywhere else in order to prevent possible problems. Usage of global variables are considered a bad practice, but I think it's safe to cautiously use in this concrete case.

**gulpfile.js:**

```
global.config = { hello: 'World!' };
require('./foo');
```

**foo.js:**

```
console.log(config.hello); // "World!"
```

---

Also, consider to use the [gulp-require-tasks](https://github.com/betsol/gulp-require-tasks) module to load your tasks from individual files.